# Cancel Grant ALL Request

Tags: mysql

I run this command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'host';
```

Now I would cancel this request without revoking the other rights of `user` database Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to restore the permissions for `user`? Or that you only want `user` to have ALL privileges on `user` database? Your question is unclear.

Comment: My user have some right `select, create index , ...` , i execute the request above by error , now i would cancel this request without lose the other rights

Comment: Did you create a backup before running the query? There is no way to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

the opposite of your GRANT statement is REVOKE ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'host;